# How do I locate an app on the iPhone spring board / home screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, springboard

As an iOS developer I have many (>150) apps installed on my iPhone. Sometimes I cannot figure out on which home screen an app is located.

I know how to start the app by using the search. And if the app uses a lot of storage I can go to "Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage" and delete it.

**But is there any way to find the installed app in the spring board without looking at every home page and in every folder?**

Comment: By 'find an installed app' do you mean find out which folder it's located or find out which home page it's located?

Comment: No. I wish I could 3D Touch or force touch from Siri results to delete the apps or see the path to the folder and app. Either Apple hasn’t figured out how they want to design this experience or they believe people will either offload unused apps or use the list view to delete as a workaround.

Comment: @fsb Best would be both. Sometimes I want to put a new app next to an already installed one and I need to know how to navigate there.